# struct transform LIFO to FIFO

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elt {
    struct elt *next; // Elément suivant
    struct elt *precedent;
    int value; // Valeur stockée dans le noeud
} ELT, *pELT;
pELT head=NULL;

pELT addElt(pELT head, int v) {
    pELT n;

    n=malloc(sizeof(ELT));
    n->value = v;
    n->next = head;

    return n;
}

void printElts(pELT l) {
    pELT p;

    for(p = l; p; p=p->next) {
        printf("Valeur : %d\n", p->value);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    head = addElt(head, 1);
    head = addElt(head, 2);
    head = addElt(head, 3);
    printElts(head);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to transform this LIFO(Last in first out) struct to FIFO (First in first out).
I don't want to change the main. I just want to print in FIFO instead of LIFO

Comment: Do you want to change the object in memory or just print it in FIFO order?

Comment: um...add function popFrontElt and call it a day?

Comment: just print fifo order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now you "prepend" the elements to the list, which is a kind of a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29):

```
n = malloc(sizeof(ELT));
n->value = v;
n->next = head;
```

if you want to "append" the elements to the end of the list, making it a kind of a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29), you just need to pass the "add element" task down the list (e.g. recursively), until it reaches the end:

```
pELT addElt(pELT head, int v) {
  if "head->next is NULL" {
    // end of list reached, put "v" here
  } else { 
    // we're in the middle of the list, go on with the child:
    head->next = addElt(head->next, v)
  }
}
```

this is just an idea, the implementation is pretty straight-forward